# "No Definition" error while compiling the program

Tags: c, usb, hid, stm32

I have compiled a USB program for STM32F0. I called a function to register the interface:

```
USBD_CUSTOM_HID_RegisterInterface(&hUsbDeviceFS, &USBD_CustomHID_fops).
```

But I am getting the error below. I can't find out the problem, because it doesn't point at any particular line:

```
Error[Li005]: no definition for "USBD_CustomHID_fops" [referenced from C:\Users\Istma1\Downloads\stm32cubef0\STM32Cube_FW_F0_V1.0.0\USB7\USB5\USB5\Projects\EWARM\USB3 Configuration\Obj\main.o]
```

Comment: error about not finding definition of `USBD_CustomHID_fops`. where you defined that function?

Comment: Have to assigned the fops `USBD_CustomHID_fops`

Comment: I didn't add the source file with main. rare and silly mistake. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it looks like you just copy-pasted that call from somewhere, and failed to also copy the `USBD_CustomHID_fops` declaration that it references. It might refer to a structure declared like this:

```
typedef struct _USBD_CUSTOM_HID_Itf
{
uint8_t *pReport;
int8_t (* Init) (void);
int8_t (* DeInit) (void);
int8_t (* OutEvent) (uint8_t, uint8_t );
}USBD_CUSTOM_HID_ItfTypeDef;
```

where you are supposed to fill in your callback pointers.

Comment: thanks a lot...actually my source file wasn't added in library. silly mistake. but thanks anyway.

Comment: then the problem is occuring again. I declared it in hid_if.h and hid_if.c file. and I called  the callback funtion of the register interface from main. But it still says no definition. Thank you.

Comment: what can be the problem @unwind

Comment: It's a linker error, so probably you're not building it properly. It should be something like `$ gcc -o usb main.c hid_if.c` (plus a whole bunch of `-I` and perhaps some `-l` options, of course).

Comment: I am not using gcc compiler. I am using iar workbench. i kinda copied the the whole example. but it seems pretty complicated right now. what is the solution now.

Comment: I just created a new project and tried to add that. It worked. I dont know any reason behind that. Thank you.